# iOS Mail is incorrectly creating [Gmail]Bin and [Gmail]Spam labels for deleting mail or marking mail as spam

Tags: ios, mail.app, email, gmail

I'm using iOS Mail connected to a Gmail account on an iPhone 7+ running iOS 14.6.

Suddenly and without warning:

- Deleting an email in iOS Mail doesn't place it in the Gmail bin but assigns it a label `[Gmail]Bin`.
- Marking something as junk mail within iOS Mail doesn't place it in the Gmail Spam folder, but assigns it a label `[Gmail]Spam`.

Looking in the `Bin` on iOS mail shows me no deleted items. It should list 172 items in the bin on the Gmail server.

When I go into the "Advanced" settings within my account details on my phone, I can see that the `Deleted Mailbox` is configured to use `Bin` on the server and not `[Gmail]Bin`. There is no option to change where junk is put.

How can I ensure that iOS Mail lists (and places items) in the correct folders on the Gmail server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical, 15 minutes after I post the question I wonder "*what would happen if I just deleted the GMail account in iOS and then add it back in again?*"

After doing that, deleted items and spam are now going into the correct Gmail folders.